# Dell 9350 , ubuntu 16.04 , bluetooth mouse Dell WM615 connect and then disconnect after short time

Tags: 16.04, mouse, dell, bluetooth

i'm going mad with a bluetooth mouse ... i see many question and many people solve the problem but not me unfortunately ...

I have a Bluetooth mouse Dell WM615 and a Dell 9350 Notebook Developer Edition. The Developer edition comes with a stock ubuntu 14.04 but the Bluetooth 4.x technology was not recognized , so i try with the last version of ubuntu 16.04 ...

With the last version i am able to pair and connect the mouse but after some seconds (sometimes 5 seconds ...) the mouse stop to work. The icon show the mouse is connected but it doesn't work  ...

so i look in internet and i try everything .

- install Blueman and trust the device ... DONE
- put the key in
  /var/lib/bluetooth/E4:A4:71:24:B0:C5/FB:2F:B1:7E:E3:14/info ... DONE
- remove the kernel module and readd ... DONE
- rfkill block bluetooth && rfkill unblock bluetooth ... DONE
- remove, disconnect , pair , connect and trust from blueman ... DONE
- download the firmware of the bluetooth ... DONE

every command here let me use the mouse for some seconds and then the mouse stop to work ... sometime i can use for 10 minutes , sometimes i can use it for at least 3 seconds ... and it drive me crazy.

here i post the result of lspci , lsusb and dmesg

lspci :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 0a)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 010f (rev 01)
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg

```
http://pastebin.com/DdK8Vupt
```

i need help , i want to throw my computer out of the window!
I read somewhere this bug can be related to the powerindicator bug in ubuntu , if so ... how can check and be sure of this problem ? and there is a way to solve it ?

ps. the mouse working well with another computer, so unfortunately it's not a mouse problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: same problem here with an XPS13 Developer edition and 16.04!

Comment: Hi @NicolaPezzotti , please let me know if you found something, i will update this thread also. Thanks Ciao!

Comment: I upgraded the packages in the distro (including bluez) and now it works a bit better. I can now use the mouse without too much hassle in the office.
I still have problems at home though! It looks like a stability issue of the connection.

Comment: @NicolaPezzotti sometime my synaptic touchpad crash and i can't use it ... same happend to you ?

Comment: also :( 
not so often though,  mainly I drag a window to the left to trigger the auto-resize. The left/right buttons will still work.

Comment: See the answer on this post for the simplest method I found to get bluetooth working on my Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/880745/ubuntu-16-04-bluetooth-not-working-dell-xps13/920803#920803